# Jest with jest-teamcity-reporter is intermittently reporting one test as failed

Tags: javascript, jestjs, teamcity

I have a very weird problem. I am using Jest for my react based javascript code unit testing. Also, I am using jest-teamcity-reporter to integrate test result into TeamCity CI. Intermittently one of the tests is reported as failed in the TeamCity even though the test is passed.

JEST console report says all test passed
[image]

TeamCity report (ignore the count that will not match with the previous image as some of the test names are duplicated)
[image]

Now I am not sure how to debug and resolve it. What parameters or logs to look for? I am unable to reproduce the issue in my local dev environment.

Strangely when it fails it will always report the first test as failed.

I added teamcity parameters to log original service messages and it seems there are failed tests.
[image: Marked failed test has no service message as failed]

Comment: You can add TeamCity configuration parameter "teamcity.build.serviceMessages.logOriginal" with value "true" and then inspect the ##teamcity messages in the Verbose build log: if there is ""##teamcity[testFailed" message, then the reporter / test statuses are to be investigated.

Comment: @Yaegor I tried and there are no failed tests

Comment: If you got no occurrences of "##teamcity[testFailed" in the verbose build log but still got a failed test reported, you can send the full build log to TeamCity support for investigation. If you got the text in the log, then the request should rather go to jest-teamcity-reporter.